# Помогите разобраться с непонятным Segmentation fault

Tags: c, массивы, gcc

Есть вот такой кусок кода:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ISIZE 1000
#define JSIZE 1000

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  double a[ISIZE][JSIZE];
  double b[1000][1000];
}
```

После запуска выкидывает SegFault. Если закомментить объявление массива b[1000][1000], то всё работает. В чём дело никак не пойму.

Comment: Создавайте массив не на стеке а в кучке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очевидно, что программа не может разместить в стеке два массива, которые в совокупности занимают по крайней мере (если `sizeof( double )` равно 8)

```
8 * 1000 * 1000 + 8 * 1000 * 1000 ,байт
```

то есть порядка 16 Мбайт.

Вам следует разместить эти массивы в статической памяти. Вы можете сделать это двумя способами. Либо сделать эти массивы глобальными. Например,

```
//...
double a[ISIZE][JSIZE];
double b[1000][1000];

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
}
```

Либо объявить их с классом памяти `static` внутри `main`

```
//...

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    static double a[ISIZE][JSIZE];
    static double b[1000][1000];
}
```

Ну, и, кончено, вы могли бы создать эти массивы динамически, используя, например, функцию `malloc

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    double ( *a )[[JSIZE] = malloc( sizeof( double[ISIZE][JSIZE] ) );
    double ( *b )[1000] = malloc( sizeof( double[1000][1000] ) );
}
```

`

Comment: Да, точно, поставил static и всё заработало. Спасибо!

Comment: @hunter Не за что. Спрашивайте еще.:)

Answer (score 1):

Происходит переполнение стека. Суммарный размер массивов a и b составляет 16Mb что видимо больше стандартного размера стека Вашей конфигурации. Если необходимы массивы больших размеров - размещайте их в динамической памяти.